# Tomcat 7 setenv.sh is not found

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, setenv

I downloaded and extracted the [apache-tomcat-7.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html#Introduction). As per the instructions in the RUNNING.txt (%CATALINA_BASE%/RUNNING.txt), it should set the JRE_HOME in the "setenv.sh" file.

Where is this file located ? Documentation said, it would be in CATALINA_HOME/bin directory. However this file is not present there.

Answer (score 31):

Documentation actually mentions the absence of the `setenv.(sh|bat)` file (by default):

> (3.4) Using the "setenv" script (optional, recommended)
>
> Apart from CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE, all environment variables
> can be specified in the "setenv" script. The script is placed either
> into CATALINA_BASE/bin or into CATALINA_HOME/bin directory and is
> named setenv.bat (on Windows) or setenv.sh (on *nix). The file has to
> be readable.
>
> By default the setenv script file is absent. If the script file is
> present both in CATALINA_BASE and in CATALINA_HOME, the one in
> CATALINA_BASE is preferred.
>
> For example, to configure the JRE_HOME and CATALINA_PID variables you
> can create the following script file:
>
> On Windows, %CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat:
>
> ```
>   set "JRE_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre@MIN_JAVA_VERSION@"
>   exit /b 0
> ```
>
> On *nix, $CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh:
>
> ```
>   JRE_HOME=/usr/java/latest
>   CATALINA_PID="/run/tomcat.pid"
> ```

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/10.1.9/RUNNING.txt#L151

Answer (score 13):

Just create one yourself; it isn't part of the distribution. It's not that hard. For your case, simply add

```
JRE_HOME=/path/to/your/java/installation
```

to the file and make it executable (`chmod 755 setenv.sh`).

You can also add other options (e.g. `-Xmx`) if necessary.

Comment: shouldn't it be `export JRE_HOME=...` ?

Comment: Ghm, I use a similar command for `CATALINA_OPTS` and it works without exporting. In any way OP can confirm this.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't find the "setenv.sh"  or "setenv.bat" in bin folder of tomcat, follow the following setps:

1. Create new file in bin folder of tomcat.
2. Rename it to `setenv.sh` for **linux** user or `setenv.bat` for **windows** user
3. Now you can set multiple thing into this file:

*Setting JRE_HOME*

For **linux** user

```
JRE_HOME=/path/to/jre/jre6
```

For **Windows** user

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Path\to\jre\jdk6
```

*Setting JAVA_OPTS*

For **linux** user

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms512m -Xmx512m -DFOOBAR_CONFIGURATION_FILE=file:///C:/foobar.properties"
```

For **windows** user

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms512m -Xmx512m -DFOOBAR_CONFIGURATION_FILE=file:///D:\foobar.properties"
```

**Restart tomcat after setting variables**.
That's it.

Comment: Great!! Worked for me

Comment: These options usually goes in the CATALINA_OPTS though as JAVA_OPTS is used by the internal Tomcat commands too: stop process, the version command etc.

Answer (score 1):

User Mindas' answer is completely correct: it is necessary to create the `setenv.sh` file in either the `CATALINA_HOME` or `CATALINA_BASE` directory, as the comment in the `catalina.sh` file indicates.

However, there is a "chicken and egg" problem wherein Tomcat must guess the location of the `CATALINA_HOME/bin/` directory in the case where the `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable is not set.

I have encountered this situation on a Ubuntu server where fortunately Tomcat guesses the `CATALINA_HOME/bin/` directory correctly.  For a single-user environment where customization of Tomcat for different users isn't necessary, it seems that setting the `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME` environment variable in the `catalina.sh` script would be a solution to the "chicken and egg" problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I downloaded Tomcat for Windows. It also came with Linux shell scripts, so I created a 'setenv.sh' and tried to run it from Windows Subsystem for Linux, but got the above error. The issue was that the non-binary shell scripts were formatted for Windows, and Linux didn't know how to run them. After converting them to Linux format, it was able to recognize and run the scripts. Try this to convert from Windows to Linux:

```
dos2unix $CATALINA_HOME/bin/*.sh
```