# Configure Tomcat to Log all Jar Files and/or Classes Loaded at Startup

Tags: tomcat

I have a rogue jar being loaded into my tomcat instance. I would like to be able to tell where the corresponding jar file is being loaded from. If not available, I would like to be able to see where a class that is in that jar is being loaded from.

I have looked at the ~/conf/logging.properties file, but from that it is not clear to me how to specify what I want.

Or, is this something one does from startup.sh as a java option?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to answer my own question. I added -verbose:class to the JAVA_OPTS of the tomcat setenv.sh file. This made all class loading information get written to the catalina.out log and I found my rogue jar!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was no setenv.sh file as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18936348/6854902).So I added the -verbose:class to the JAVA_OPTS in catalina.sh file using the below line and it worked.

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -verbose:class"`

> Note: JAVA_OPTS variable was already present in the file.I just added the verbose option using the above command.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? also, add it to the JAVA_OPTS within catalina.sh

```
-XX:+TraceClassLoading
```